# Service is not starting on Centos on boot

Tags: centos, init.d, chkconfig, linux

I have a service installed to start jasper reporting server on boot. I believe it is correctly setup.

here is the startup script placed in /etc/init.d/jasperserver

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jasperserver
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start JasperServer at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by JasperServer.
### END INIT INFO

JASPER_HOME="/opt/jaspersoft/jasperreports-server-5.5"

case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      echo "Starting JasperServer"
      sudo -u ec2-user $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh start
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      echo "Stopping JasperServer"
      sudo -u ec2-user $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh stop

    fi
    ;;
  restart)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      echo "Restarting JasperServer"
      sudo -u ec2-user $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh restart
    fi
    ;;
  status)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      sudo -u ec2-user $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh status
    fi
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Also, I run the command

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/jasperserver
```

I then have run the commands

```
sudo chkconfig --add jasperserver
sudo chkconfig jasperserver on
```

If I run:

```
chkconfig --list  | grep jasper
```

I see:

```
jasperserver    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

I can also run:

```
sudo service jasperserver (start|stop|restart)
```

successfully

However when I issue a reboot, the service isn't running. I wondered if there's a way I can get logging information or enable logging to be able to tackle this.

---

More detail

```
uname -a
Linux jaspersoft.localdomain 3.10.42-52.145.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 10 23:46:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also after adding the line:

```
# chkconfig: 2345 70 30
```

the symlinks are as follows:

```
[ec2-user@jaspersoft ~]$ ls -laF /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/*jasper*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug  6 08:09 /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S70jasperserver -> ../init.d/jasperserver*
```

and likewise for /etc/rc.d/rc[2-5].d/*jasper*

Comment: it can be util if you say your centos version, anyway are you sure you don't have nothing in your log?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a `# chkconfig: - 30 60` line in your start-up script mandating the order number in the startup sequence (30) or shutdown (60) sequence.

What symlinks are being set up in `/etc/rc[0-6].d/` for your service?

IIRC when none is defined prio 50 is used. That could result in trying to start your service before other dependancies have been started.

Answer (score 3):

A stock CentOS installation will typically have `Defaults requiretty` set in `/etc/sudoers`. This will cause `sudo -u $user $command` to fail inside an init script on startup, as the script isn't necessarily running in a "complete" tty.

Usefully, CentOS provides a common init functions file (`/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`) that contains the `daemon` function - a wrapper for running programs with different options (e.g., user, nice, pid files, etc.).

Try modifying your script as follows:

```
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

...

  start)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      echo "Starting JasperServer"
      daemon --user $JASPER_USER $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh start
    fi
  ;;
```

This will use `runuser -s /bin/bash $user` to create a shell with the correct permissions in order to run the command, neatly avoiding any environment-meddling or security issues with `su` or `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and I believe the issue is regarding this line:

```
sudo -u ec2-user ....
```

This is the new script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# chkconfig: 2345 96 14
#
# Start/Stop of JasperReports Server
#

JASPER_HOME="/opt/jaspersoft/jasperreports-server-5.5"

JASPER_USER=ec2-user


case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      echo "Starting JasperServer"
      su $JASPER_USER -c "$JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh start"
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      echo "Stopping JasperServer"
      su $JASPER_USER -c "$JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh stop"
    fi
    ;;
  restart)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      echo "Restarting JasperServer"
      su $JASPER_USER -c "$JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh restart"
    fi
    ;;
  status)
    if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
      su $JASPER_USER -c "$JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh status"
    fi
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```